# Docker container localhost access issue

Tags: docker, networking

I have docker running inside VM. I'm running 2 containers as can be seen below (removed noise).

> [abc_dev@abclocaldev ~]$ docker ps
>
> ```
> NAMES             PORTS                     
>
> happy_stallman                                          
>
> repository        0.0.0.0:30081->8081/tcp
> ```

**repository** has an app running which can be accessible from port 30081. I can access this from VM as well as host machine (port forwarding on VM).
**happy_stallman** fails to access repository on 127.0.0.1:30081, I am getting *Connection refused*.

Does anyone know whats going on?

I would like to add that **happy_stallman** is able to access google as well as other app on intranet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, docker containers are running on the `bridge` network. When you are trying to access `127.0.0.1:8080` from inside the container, you are accessing container's `8080` port.

To demonstrate, lets try to access another container using it's IP address. Start simple server:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8080:8080 trinitronx/python-simplehttpserver
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8080 ...
```

Then switch to another terminal and check that `8080` is exposed to the host:

```
$ wget 127.0.0.1:8080
--2018-10-02 10:51:14--  http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 178 [text/html]
Saving to: <<index.html.5>>

index.html.5                               100%[=====================================================================================>]     178  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2018-10-02 10:51:14 (18.9 MB/s) - <<index.html.5>> saved [178/178]
```

The container served a file, works fine. Now lets try to do the same thing using another container:

```
$ docker run -it alpine wget 127.0.0.1:8080
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:8080 (127.0.0.1:8080)
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

Does not work, because `127.0.0.1` here is the `alpine`s local address, not the host address.

To get container IP use the following command:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' 4f1fe52be173
172.17.0.3
```

Where `4f1fe52be173` is the container name. After specifying correct IP, the container is able to access another container port:

```
$ docker run -it alpine wget 172.17.0.3:8080
Connecting to 172.17.0.3:8080 (172.17.0.3:8080)
index.html           100% |*******************************|   178   0:00:00 ETA
```

---

This could be simplified if you are using docker-compose:

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: trinitronx/python-simplehttpserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  client:
    image: alpine
    command: wget web:8080
    depends_on:
      - web

$ docker-compose up
Creating soon_web_1 ... done
Creating soon_client_1 ... done
Attaching to soon_web_1, soon_client_1
web_1     | soon_client_1.soon_default - - [02/Oct/2018 05:59:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
client_1  | Connecting to web:8080 (172.20.0.2:8080)
client_1  | index.html           100% |*******************************|   178   0:00:00 ETA
client_1  |
soon_client_1 exited with code 0
```

As you can see, there are no direct specifications of containers IP addresses. Instead you are accessing the container port using `web:8080`.

Note, that `depends_on` does not wait until a container is "ready". For better control please read this guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/